# Django errors about HTTP_HOST from domain an extra dot after it

Tags: django, nginx

I'm all over the `ALLOWED_HOSTS` setting in Django. It has been set on all my production sites for a while now but one site in particular has been throwing out weird debug emails. The site works fine (for me) but about once a week I'll get an email along the lines of:

```
 SuspiciousOperation: Invalid HTTP_HOST header 
  (you may need to set ALLOWED_HOSTS): thepcspy.com.


<WSGIRequest
path:/,
GET:<QueryDict: {}>,
POST:<QueryDict: {}>,
COOKIES:{},
META:{...
 'HTTP_HOST': 'thepcspy.com.',
 'SERVER_NAME': 'thepcspy.com',
...
```

Notice the full stop after the domain in the error and in `HTTP_HOST`. As far as I can see in my nginx config, there isn't anything that could add an extra dot after the name on `HTTP_HOST` (note that `SERVER_NAME` is correct). What on earth is going on here?

Should I just write this off as somebody intentionally trying to break my server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The final dot makes it a [fully qualified domain name (FQDN)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name). This issue is noted precisely in the Django docs on the `ALLOWED_HOSTS` setting: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts

> If you want to also allow the fully qualified domain name (FQDN), which some browsers can send in the Host header, you must explicitly add another ALLOWED_HOSTS entry that includes a trailing period.